# How to restart nginx on remote server

Tags: linux, nginx, gitlab-ci

I have a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab. My runner is established on a remote server. My publish source is established on a remote server based on nginx. In the server where my source is published, I created a "gitlab" user. everything is well, but I need to restart nginx server. I use the following code :

```
script:
       - ssh  gitlab@IPADDRESS 'systemctl restart nginx'
```

but I got the below error :

```
Failed to restart nginx.service: Interactive authentication required.
```

How I can restart nginx server remotely

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to be the sudo user to execute the command.
You can try something like this:

```
script:
   - echo "password" | ssh  gitlab@IPADDRESS 'sudo -S systemctl restart nginx'
```

Where password is the users password. Ofcourse, you should be mindful of the fact that the password is in plain sight of anybody who can read the configuration file.